# MVC 5 jquery change value form other View

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an MVC 5 App.

I have defined in the`_Layout` a View that is the `Header`, another that is the `Body` and the `Footer` like this...

```
<div>
    @Html.Action("Header", "Home")
</div>

<div>
    @RenderBody()
    <footer>
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/Footer.cshtml")
    </footer>
</div>
```

on Body I load a `View` that Execute an `@Ajax.BeginHtml`. It returns a `Json` on success.

What I need, in order to not Load() all the page, is to change a `@Html.Editor` of `Header.cshtml` from the `Body.cshtml` using `Jquery` on `success` method

Is that posible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you set the UpdateTargetId to the element containing the editor and set to action to return a partialview with the editor in it.

For example

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "target"
        })) { }
```

where UpdateTargetId is the element containing the Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. @Html.Editor just renders some html markup so you could changed its content using jQuery. You won't be able to change the strongly-typed model from it with jQuery, if that's your case.

Could you provide an example of what you are trying to achieve?